# How to create a copy of an array of values and an array of pointers without std?

Tags: c++, struct, copy, copy-constructor

I can't figure out how to make a copy of this structure:

```
struct Node {
private:
    int *keys_;
    int min_degree_;
    Node **children_;
    int count_;
    bool is_leaf_;
    ...
```

Well, I understand about half of it:

```
Node(Node const &node) {
    min_degree_ = node.min_degree_;
    is_leaf_ = node.is_leaf_;
    count_ = node.count_;
    ...
}
```

And how to make a copy of the value array(int *keys_) and pointer array(Node **children_) without std is not clear. The original object has to be deleted, so the references can be copied, though I'm not sure.

Comment: The struct itself does not contain the data of the arrays that *keys_, *children_ pointing to. So, if you copy this struct, you just simply copy those pointers (the addresses of the arrays). 
In case, you want to copy the data that *key_ and *children_ pointing to, you must know the array lengths, copy them to somewhere in memory, get the memory addresses and set the new addresses to the *key_, *children_ in the new struct.
It is recommended to do research about pointer before working with them, otherwise, you would experience so much pain as I did :D

Comment: *"without std is not clear"*. Do it with std :-) If you cannot use std, create your own simplified version of the std components you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.